# Use org-contacts in mu4e email auto completion

Tags: mu4e

I have a contacts.org with following structure:

```
* Family
** Person 1
:PROPERTIES:
:TITLE:
:ALIAS:
:COMPANY:
:ROLE:
:EMAIL:    
:MOBILE:
:WORK_PHONE:
:ADDRESS:
:URL:
:BIRTHDAY: 
:ITOLD_THEM_EMAIL:
:ITOLD_THEM_PHONE:
:NOTES:
:CREATED:
:END:
** Person 2
* Friends
** Person 1
** Person 2
* Clients
** Person 1
** Person 2
* Acquaintances
** Person 1
** Person 2
```

I try to use these information to compose email address completion, probably by using `mu4e-contact-process-function`, `mu4e-contacts-func`, `mu4e-org-contacts-file`, but I have no idea how to glue these things together. The documentation

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing; the mu4e documentation mentions how to store org-contacts, but not how to use them (in autocompletion).  I found [mu4e-contacts](https://gitlab.com/voidyourwarranty/mu4e-contacts) which I didn't try yet, but might be what we're looking for.

Comment: BTW, to get `mu4e-contacts` to work, I had to use `(setq mu4e-mu-home "~/.cache/mu/")` (since my mu cache sits in the default dir).